# Missed tiles on Android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I work on a fishing app that needs to handle many locations in the middle of the water. I noticed that after zoom 13, **only in Android**, most of the locations in the water does not return a tile and I see a blank space instead (satellite map)

[image]

This is not random but consistent, zoom level greater than 13 return just empty, **this does not happen in iOS**.

In some locations, even a zoom level of 11 returns empty. I'm ok to use a smaller zoom level in the middle of the water, but the thing is that I don't know when the map is going to return empty.

I have read that google map does not have a full coverage of the world so empty tiles could be expected.

Two questions:

- Why this is happening Android only (maps version 16.0.0)?
- How can I detect missed tiles so I can react in consecuence?

Comment: Please add coordinates of location with no tiles.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko: in the picture you have an example `-43, 119`. In any case, basically anything in the middle of the ocean gives me the same result.

Comment: Yes, you're right - something strange is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in maps SDK for Android https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172359726

I was able to reproduce the problem with v2 and v3 (beta).